# Set more partitions than consumers at once or set equal and dynamically increase when necessary?

Tags: apache-kafka

What is the best way to work with partition and consumer balance in Kafka? Set up 1 consumer 5 partitions and increase the number of consumers if necessary or should I keep them equal and increase at the same time when there are more messages than expected?

Comment: Starting with only one consumer might make you implement bad design patterns such as assuming you have ordering within the consumed records, or otherwise storing the data within in-memory data-structures and assuming you'll always get "all records" in that consumer instance... When you scale it up, neither will be true.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to increase the number of consumers when needed. No need to over provision if the current number of consumers can properly handle the current load.

It is also common to set on creation a number of partitions that allows you to easily handle the expected future load mid/long-term. You can always increase the number of partitions of a topic, but that will most likely reshuffle your keys, which for certain applications may be problematic and take some effort to do it properly.